# A semiprime only has $4$ factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

It seems quite trivial, but I can't figure out how to explain that in general a semiprime $pq$ only has $4$ factors (namely $1, p, q, pq$). Can anyone give me a small proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true when the semi-prime is the square of a prime. Here is a hint for the case where the primes are distinct:

The number of divisors of $n$ is

$\sigma_0(n)=(a_1+1)(a_2+1)...(a_t+1),$

where $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_t}...p_t^{a_t}$ is the canonical prime factorization of $n$.

Edit: That is, assuming you were asserting they had $4$ factors as opposed to *at most* $4$ factors.

Comment: Thanks, that way I get it. Now I have to figure out why that formula for the number of divisors works.

Comment: @ArnoudNijon Can you formulate a condition for divisibility in terms of prime factorisations?